# Clash of clans base layout types?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Alright guys I have clash of clans and I have a town hall level 6. What are the different base types and what are the purposes of each? I am asking because I am sick of losing trophies left and right during war. When this happens I drop in the clan rankings and then I cant be in the wars. please help.

Answer (score 2):

I will post a link with a whole article dedicated to different clan layouts.  Basically it all depends on what you're looking to do.  For your purposes, not losing trophies, you'll want to center your clan castle and build up as many defenses around it as possible, to keep things away from getting your castle and instantly winning the battle, in turn killing your trophies.  Here is an article explaining what different layouts are, advice on how to set your base up, and I'll even link a place where people give layouts that have worked the best for them, give them a try and see which one's work for you.

**Farming Base**:  A base that is used if you're looking to protect and keep your loot as high as possible.  If you're saving up to upgrade your TH, or something else, this will be the base for you.  Potential for a lot of trophy loss here, as usually you set your TH outside so people attack it for an easy win and then leave.

**Trophy Farming Base**:  This layout will help guard your Town Hall over anything else.  It is used when you don't care as much about the loot, but more about getting as many trophies as you can get, staying high on your clan in terms of trophies.  It will make it harder for people to get to your base and get that guaranteed star that comes with destroying the base.

**War Base**:  This is usually pretty close to a Trophy Base, as it protects your Town Hall over all else.  There are subcategories of these bases, such as "*Hog Resistant*" bases, that will protect more against attacks using Hog Riders(which are popular in wars).  They usually keep the TH and Clan Castle close together, as to force the attacker to make it past some of your defenses before the clan castle is released.

[CoC Layouts](http://www.gamatrix.com/clash-of-clans/baselayouts)

[CoC Layout Explanation](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Layouts)

Comment: You should be explaining the layouts here, not just linking elsewhere.  That way, if the pages ever go down, your answer is still valid.

Comment: I was in the middle of an edit doing that

Comment: You're now explaining what types of bases they are, but you have no details about how to lay them out, which is what is being asked for.

Comment: The exact question was "What are the different base types and what are the purposes of each?" Has nothing to do with how they are laid out, just explanation of what the different kind of bases are used for!

Comment: totally agree. this is a very good answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major base design categories, and which you pick depends on whether you care about your trophies or your resources.

The "Farming Base" prioritizes resources.  You leave your Town Hall outside your walls, and bring your storages towards the center, protected by overlapping defenses.  Usually collectors, camps, and barracks buildings are around the outside of the base.

The goal of this base is to keep enemies from hitting your storages.  Most good base designs will make it so that you have to destroy most or all of the base in order to destroy all of the storages, which means that the storages are distributed (NOT bunched together) and well defended.

The "Trophy Base" prioritizes protecting the Town Hall.  The goal is to minimize the number of stars an attacker can take from your base.  Generally it's hard to prevent 1-star losses, since all that is required is destruction of half your buildings.  As the size of your base grows, this becomes more and more difficult since walls are limited.  Here, you want the Town Hall as close to the middle as possible, and then defenses should cover as many buildings as possible.

War Bases are *always* Trophy Bases.  In wars, only stars count.  Thus, if your normal base is a Farming Base, you'll want to change the layout for war.

Within these categories, many different styles of base are possible.  You generally want your mortars, wizard towers, and air defenses defending key choke points in the base, and ideally their ranges overlap and they support each other.  Walls should be used to segment the base and keep attacking troops busy.

If you just want to copy a layout someone else has already developed, [here is one site where people upload their base designs.](http://clashofclansbuilder.com/)  You can filter by Town Hall level to see bases you can build with the buildings you have at TH6.

---

However, knowing this is probably not especially helpful, since your question says that your problem is losing trophies and falling out of the eligible list for war.

Really, even with a Farming Base it's not that hard to maintain your trophy count.  Just don't break your shield without taking a win or two from some other player.  The wins you get should balance out the trophies you lose from having your Town Hall hit.

You can also leave most of your base well defended, but then leave a storage outside your walls.  Farmers will often hit an undefended storage and then give up, giving you a bunch of free trophies.  I only suggest this when you don't need a particular resource - for example, elixir when you're saving up gold to upgrade defenses.

If you are consistently finding that raiders are 2- or 3-starring your base, chances are you haven't spent enough time upgrading your defenses.  Focus on your upgrades for a while, or you'll be a liability when war comes.  Leave your town hall for last - always!  Yes, even after walls!

Comment: what level wall does it require me to upgrade my town hall

Comment: @DavidEckert, max out your walls and everything else before you upgrade your Town Hall.  It's not a requirement, but a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Farming Base:** A base that is used if you're looking to protect and keep your loot as high as possible. If you're saving up to upgrade your TH, or something else, this will be the base for you. Potential for a lot of trophy loss here, as usually you set your TH outside so people attack it for an easy win and then leave.

*Example TH 6 Farming Base* (notice the town hall is located outside the walls)

[image]

**Trophy Farming Base:** This layout will help guard your Town Hall over anything else. It is used when you don't care as much about the loot, but more about getting as many trophies as you can get, staying high on your clan in terms of trophies. It will make it harder for people to get to your base and get that guaranteed star that comes with destroying the base.

*Example TH 6 Trophy/Defensive Base* (notice the town hall is protected)

[image]

**War Base:** This is usually pretty close to a Trophy Base, as it protects your Town Hall over all else. There are subcategories of these bases, such as "Hog Resistant" bases, that will protect more against attacks using Hog Riders(which are popular in wars). They usually keep the TH and Clan Castle close together, as to force the attacker to make it past some of your defenses before the clan castle is released.

*Example TH 6 War Base*

[image]

Images grabbed from [1337 Wiki](http://1337wiki.com/clash-clans/base-designs/level-6/)

Comment: This looks like a exact copy of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/202327/75275 except with added pictures.